# How do I iterate over collections generically in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, ienumerable, stdvector, stdset

Simply put, if I have a set and vector how do I create a generic method that can handle both as params.

All I want to do, is iterate over either types of collections.  Sounds like it should be trivial but I'm missing something.

```
void printMeSomeStrings(somebaseclass<string> strings) {
  for (auto& str : strings) {
    cout << str << endl;
  }
}
```

In C#, I would pass IEnumerable or something like that.  Then I could iterate over the collection.

Any general reading explaining the answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is to put the code doing the iterating in a template.  This requires exposing the implementation to everyone who uses it, which has disadvantages.

Basically, take a type `C` as a `template` parameter, then write your code in terms of that type `C`.

```
template<typename C>
void printMeSomeStrings(C&& strings) {
  for (auto const& str : strings) {
    cout << str << endl;
  }
}
```

If you want to be able to have a strong barrier between interface and implementation, the C++11 approach would be to engage in type erasure on a `for`-iterable container, and then expose a `for`-iterable container, like how `std::function` works.

This is trickier.  I personally find writing a `for_each` function easier than writing a full blown iteration adapter.  If you want the full blown container iteration type erasure object, start with `boost`, or ask me below and I might do it.

The `for_each` adaptor is easy, however.

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct for_each_helper_interface {
  virtual ~for_each_helper_interface() {}
  virtual void for_each( std::function< void(T) > const& ) = 0;
};
template<typename C, typename T>
struct for_each_helper:for_each_helper_interface<T> {
  C& c;
  for_each_helper( C& in ):c(in) {}
  virtual void for_each( std::function< void(T) > const& f ) override final {
    for( auto&& x:c ) {
      f(x);
    }
  }
};
template<typename T>
struct for_each_adaptor {
  std::unique_ptr<for_each_helper_interface<T>> pImpl;
  void for_each( std::function< void(T) > const& f ) {
    if (pImpl) {
      pImpl->for_each(f);
    }
  }
  template<typename C>
  for_each_adaptor( C&& c ): pImpl( new for_each_helper<C, T>( std::forward<C>(c) ) ) {}
};
```

which will type-erase the container of `T` (or a type convertible to `T`!) and expose a `for_each` method that lets you iterate over the contents of the container.  Use like this:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
void print_stufF( for_each_adaptor<std::string const&> c ) {
  c.for_each([&](std::string const&s){
    std::cout << s << "\n";
  });
}
int main() {
   std::set<std::string> s;
   s.insert("hello");
   s.insert("world");
   print_stuff(s);
   std::vector<std::string> v;
   v.push_back("hola");
   v.push_back("bola");
   print_stuff(v);
 }
```

What is going on here is that for each type used to construct our adaptor, we build a custom implementation of for each.  We then store a pointer to the abstract base class of this custom class, and redirect for each calls to it.

This means anything that specializes `std::begin` or defines its own begin need not be related: we create ad hoc relationships at point of use instead.

Live example: http://ideone.com/xOqBkI

Comment: Boost already has `any_range` which will do type erasure similar to `std::function`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use templates. For instance:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename C>
void foo(C const& c)
{
    std::cout << "{ ";
    for (auto const& x : c)
    {
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "}";
}
```

And here is how you would use it:

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
    foo(v);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::set<std::string> s = {"Hello,", "Generic", "World!"};
    foo(s);
}
```

[*Live example*.](http://ideone.com/QOsrCf)

Comment: a nice answer, if you want to avoid defining your own template you can use std::for_each with a lambda or printer function.

Answer (score 3):

This is **exactly** what iterators were designed for.

```
template <class It>
void print_some_strings(It first, It last) {
    while (first != last)
        std::cout << *first++ << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Is it just me or you are not iterating over the list? The 'last' argument is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> In C#, I would pass IEnumerable or something like that.

C++ uses the more pythonic approach of duck typing to define interfaces(generally called a concept in C++), rather than using inheritance. To do duck typing in C++, you use a template function like this:

```
template<typename C>
void printMeSomeStrings(const C& strings) 
{
    for (const auto& str : strings) 
    {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
}
```

In python, duck typing is done at runtime, but in C++ it is done at compile time, so there is no runtime cost to duck typing, and everything is checked at compile time as well.

Here is more info about C++, to help with looking for information. First, the equivalent of the `IEnumerator<T>` is the iterator in C++. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) is a page about the different iterator categories, and what needs to be implemented for iterators. For legacy reasons, iterators are modeled after pointers in C, which lets you use C arrays with the standard C++ algorithms.

However, unlike `IEnumerator<T>`, iterators must come in pairs. An iterator to the begining and the end(which is one past the last element). So, the equivalent of `IEnumerable<T>` in C++ is called a range. In C++11, a range is defined by two free functions, `begin(T)` and `end(T)`(it can also be implemented as member function `.begin()` and `.end()`).

By defining the concept(aka interface) as two free function, as opposed to using inheritance, ranges can be implemented non-intrusively. So for example, if you have work with some legacy api that uses C style linked lists. They can now be adapted as a C++11 range and used inside a C++ for loop.

Comment: This isn't duck typing - this is type inference.

Comment: @MichaelBurge Its commonly referred to as compile-time duck typing in the C++ community. See [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/templates-and-duck-typing/184401971)